Parcel.js not causing any errors with invalid imports or invalid type aliases
I have this very basic Node.JS application:
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="module" src="index.ts"></script>
</head><body></body></html>

index.ts
import { Good } from "./good";
import { Bad } from "./bad";

let test1:Good = {stringVal: "test", numberVal: 1234};
let test2:Good = {stringVal: 1234, numberVal: "test"};
let test3:Good = {};

let test4:Bad = {stringVal: "test", numberVal: 1234};
let test5:Bad = {stringVal: 1234, numberVal: "test"};
let test6:Bad = {};

console.log("Hello world!");

good.ts
export type Good = {
    stringVal: string;
    numberVal: number;
}

If I run this with ts-node index.ts, I get the errors I expect to have:
index.ts:2:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './bad' or its corresponding type declarations.
index.ts:5:19 - error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
index.ts:5:36 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
index.ts:6:5 - error TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Good': stringVal, numberVal
I want those errors to happen. However, if I run the same code with parcel index.html, no errors pop up, and I can load the page served by Parcel just fine. The objects will all be constructed properly, despite their definitions being incompatible with the definition on good.ts, ./bad not existing and the definition of Bad not being present.
I assume this is happening because of tree shaking. How can I use type aliases in Typescript, with Parcel, without having the type alias definitions being tree-shaken out?

I finally managed to figure it out. Parcel will ignore most issues on Typescript files unless you manually add a validator to .parcelrc. I don't know why that is the case, as I would expect it to behave, by default, the same way the rest of node does.
Anyway, what you need to do is to add this to .parcelrc:
"validators": {
        "*.{ts,tsx}": ["@parcel/validator-typescript"],
    }

